# Check if httponly cookie exists in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, httponly

As the question says can you find out if a cookie exists within Javascript if it is a HttpOnly? I don't need to access the information inside of it, just know it has one.

A little more information on the situation is that there was originally a web server which used a cookie as an authentication token, and it was set to httponly as it was not used by the client so it added to the security.

However now there is a change needed where the client needs to know if it has the cookie (as the site can work without the user being logged in, but if they are logged in (the auth cookie would exist) the site needs to display certain things and hide others.

There are other security precautions in place on the web server so there is no harm in the scenario where the client has an incorrect auth cookie, but the site makes it look like they are logged in, as it would delete the cookie and reject the user.

Comment: Can you not alter the server-side code to communicate the authentication status to the client as part of page creation?

Comment: There is no server side code really, its a pure html/javascript web site which also allows the users to login to persist information outside of localStorage (that's where the web-server kicks in). Originally the client was required to log in before accessing the site, however now the user can use the entire site without logging in using localStorage. This call to find out if the cookie exists is to show the login boxes or not and other remote functionality if they are logged in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. And see Rob's comments below.

See this, which you probably already saw - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly

> An HttpOnly cookie is not accessible via non-HTTP methods, such as
>   calls via JavaScript (e.g., referencing "document.cookie")...

**Edit:** Removed `undefined` response, I wrote a script that you may not be using :)

Comment: "It will return `undefined`"? Cookies are obtained through `document.cookie`, which is an always-existing string. The HttpOnly cookie just doesn't show up, but it's definitely not "`undefined`"

Comment: I mean if you try to access it and get a return value. Right?

Comment: Cookies in JavaScript have to be obtained through string manipulation on `document.cookie`. For example, `document.cookie` can look like `value=woow%20; value2=another%20woot`. To find the value of the cookie whose key name is `value`, you can use (example): `var test = /(?:;\s*|^)?woow=([^;]*)/.exec(document.cookie);` If the cookie exists, you can get the value through `test[1]`. If it doesn't `test === null`, and trying to do `test[1]` will throw a `null` error.

Answer (score 60):

I had the same problem. I solved it with the server setting another cookie, not httponly, every time it refreshed the httponly session cookie, with the same max-age and no sensitive data. Now, if one of them is present, the same goes for the other, and the client can know if the httponly counterpart is there.

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion. This also helps in case, the user suddenly clears all his cookies from a particular site.

Comment: This is the best answer. The selected answer is a hack that opens new problems.

Answer (score 54):

You can indirectly check to see if it exists by trying to set it to a value with javascript if it can't be set, then the HTTP Only Cookie must be there (or the user is blocking cookies).

```js
function doesHttpOnlyCookieExist(cookiename) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();

  document.cookie = cookiename + "=new_value;path=/;" + expires;
  return document.cookie.indexOf(cookiename + '=') == -1;
}
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining which part of this isn't working on Firefox? I'm on 66.0.3 here and it seems to work perfectly fine... getting exactly the same results as on Chrome, Edge and IE11.

Comment: Safari 13 overwrite cookie

Comment: Just tested on Safari 13.1, Firefox 76.0.1 and Chrome 83 on macOS Catalina. Worked like a charm on all 3, thanks for the brilliant trick! :D

Comment: Agreed with Ali...that is a *brilliant* trick. I suspect it will be "fixed" at some point in the future, but for now, this is what I'm going with too...

Comment: In my opinion, you shouldn't rely on this solution because it's an implementation detail. Maybe in the future, major browsers will consider this a security vulnerability and in turn allow both cookies to co-exist sharing the same name. This might very well happen because browsers already provide this feature.

Comment: Wow it worked for me and save my time as well thanks man.

Comment: This one doesn't seem to be working anymore on ios 14. I tried with ipad and iphone ios 14.x on both Chrome and Safari, neither of them worked.

Comment: Hi is there any update or alternative solution regarding IOS? it is not working on IOS

Answer (score 13):

Whenever you need to check whether the cookie exists or not, you can send a request to the server that requires authentication & check the response. If its something like `401 Unauthorized` or `403 Forbidden`, then the cookie probably doesn't exist & you can prompt the user for login.

On the other hand, if the cookie exists, it'll be automatically sent by the browser resulting in a `200 OK` response.