# How to detect if an httpOnly cookie has been set

Tags: html, cookies, reactjs, react-router, httponly

An http only cookie `uid` has been set on the browser by the server. I need to find out whether this cookie exists and take some actions in my javascript. I know that http only cookies cannot be read by javascript. So I'm thinking of setting another non-http cookie `loggedin` with the same `maxAge` as that of `uid` whenever the latter is being set from server. Both will be set together and cleared together. Will this approach work? Are there any caveats to this?

Comment: Can you just request it from the server?

Comment: How is login being handled? If it's via a React component, it's best to have the component handle this by checking for success or failure of your login service.

Comment: @PeeHaa Requesting from server is always an option. Just seeing if that can be avoided

Comment: @cmbuckley I'm trying to see if the login service has to be fired at all. If the cookie is present I'm avoiding the login call.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353630/check-if-httponly-cookie-exists-in-javascript)

My approach was to try and overwrite the cookie and it worked in Edge, Chrome and Firefox(don't know about other browsers)

This is the code I used:

```js
private doesHttpOnlyCookieExist(cookieName: string) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();

    document.cookie = cookieName + "=new_value;path=/;" + expires;
    return document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName + '=') == -1;
 }
```

And this is the explanation:

*You can indirectly check to see if it exists by trying to set it to a value with javascript if it can't be set, then the HTTP Only Cookie must be there (or the user is blocking cookies).*