# Send custom request header to each GraphQl query with Apollo Client, only when HttpOnly cookie has been set

Tags: reactjs, cookies, apollo-client, request-headers, httponly

I am using [Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/) in my React app.

When a user is logged-in in our cms we set a HttpOnly cookie. I can see in my React app (browser) when I inspect with devtools this cookie has been set: `MYNAMEffb4afd023baac83115bf7882`.

I need to send a custom Request header to each GraphQl query request. But only when above cookie has been set.

The custom header:

```
X-My-Name: Name
```

What are the steps I have to follow?

Comment: This can be done in a [link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction/)

Comment: @MichelFloyd thanks! But how do I check in React if `HttpOnly` cookie has been set? So in the custom link I can add an if statement `if (hasMyHttpOnlyCookie) {// link code}`. As far as I know you can't read an `HttpOnly` cookie in your frontend? Otherwise it will send that request header all the time in every GraphQL request. Also for 'normal' users?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63877877/2805154

Comment: @MichelFloyd thanks again. So if I am not mistaken, the way to go is setting another non-httponly cookie as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63877877/4822666). Is that correct?

Comment: That's one way. Or you could avoid cookies altogether and use custom headers and local storage.

Comment: @MichelFloyd ok but how should I use custom headers and local storage in this case. What will be the steps to get this working with local  storage variant?

Comment: @MichelFloyd is this also possible with JWT token?

Comment: Yes, you can use JWT with custom headers.

Comment: @MichelFloyd thanks I am trying it already. I raised [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74264345/make-a-condition-based-on-request-url-status-code-and-response-header-value-in-r). Do you know?